# non-$n$-colorability of an infinite graph and generic partitions of the vertices

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, infinite-graphs

I have an infinite graph $G$ and a natural number $n$, and I am interested in the property of $n$-colorability of $G$.  I have the naive idea that

> (1) if almost every partition of the vertices of $G$ into $n$ subsets is *not* an $n$-coloring, then $G$ is not $n$-colorable.

Of course, here I am being ambiguous as to what it means for something to hold for "almost every" partitions.  Is there a notion of "almost every" for which (1) is true, or another for which (1) is false?

Comment: An infinite graph is $n$-colorable iff all of its finite subgraphs are $n$-colorable. So it suffices that only a very small (finite) set of partitions has no $n$-coloring to be not $n$-colorable. But I am not sure if this is what you are looking for...